# AutoCompleteExtender ajax in asp.net ,

Tags: autocompleteextender

Hi I am using the AutoCompleteExtender ajax control. I am getting the list of strings in LIST collection. I want to populate only those strings, which user typing as prefix text. how to do this. I am following the example given in ajax toolkit.let say user typing "ca" then if list contain the list like,
'cat', 'dog', donkey', 'mouse','cart'....etc.

Then it should populate only 'cat' and cart'.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [example](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) there's a description of the properties. Quote:

> - **ServiceMethod** - The web service method to be called. The signature of
>     this method must match the following:
>
>   ```
>   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
>   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
>   public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count) { ... }
>   ```
>
> Note that you can replace
>   "GetCompletionList" with a name of
>   your choice, but the return type and
>   parameter name and type must exactly
>   match, including case.
>
> - **ServicePath** - The path to the web service that the extender will
>     pull the word\sentence completions
>     from. If this is not provided, the
>     service method should be a page
>     method.

So you need write a web service which will contain a method returning the list of suggestions based on the user input.